# can we connect with two DataBase Schemas with spring data jpa using same repository , model

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, jpa-2.0, jpa-2.1

I want to connect to two Database schemas which are on same database server , for that I want to use only one set of models and JPA repositories , with two data soources connecting to two different schemas .But as of now i am not able to find a way where we can reuse the existing models and repositories , for now I have created two sets of models and repositories having different schemas .Is there a way we can reuse the models and Repositories ?

But as of now i am not able to find a way where we can reuse the existing models and repositories , for now I have created two sets of models and repositories having different schemas

**NOTE:**

i am able to connect to two schemas via two data sources hence multi-tenancy support is not needed the only thing is while connecting to two separate schemas i am creating models(enitities) and JPA repositories twices even though tables are identical in both the schemas , is there are a to remove code duplicacy

Comment: For example : I have a entity class EMP to represent table emp_records with id , age , name , salary and one repository which extends JPA repository . Now i having two DB schemas orderManagment and new_orderManagment  .And both the schemas having table called emp_records , so who can I interact with both the schemas sharing the same entity repository and avoiding the creation of same entity and repository classes .

Answer (score 1):

looks like you need multi-tenancy support. Tenant per schema

You need TenantInterceptor which resolves tenantId e.g. from session or JWT token. And MultiTenantConnectionProvider which returns desired provider.

Some code from [Multi-Tenancy Implementation for Spring Boot + Hibernate Projects](https://dzone.com/articles/spring-boot-hibernate-multitenancy-implementation)

```
@Component
public class TenantInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {

    @Autowired  
    private JwtTokenUtil jwtTokenUtil;

    @Value("${jwt.header}")
    private String tokenHeader;

    @Override
    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler)
            throws Exception {
        String authToken = request.getHeader(this.tokenHeader);
        String tenantId = jwtTokenUtil.getTenantIdFromToken(authToken);
        TenantContext.setCurrentTenant(tenantId);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void postHandle(
            HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler, ModelAndView modelAndView)
            throws Exception {
        TenantContext.clear();
    }
}
```

and

```
@Component
public class MultiTenantConnectionProviderImpl implements MultiTenantConnectionProvider {

    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Override
    public Connection getAnyConnection() throws SQLException {
        return dataSource.getConnection();
    }

    @Override
    public void releaseAnyConnection(Connection connection) throws SQLException {
        connection.close();
    }

    @Override
    public Connection getConnection(String tenantIdentifie) throws SQLException {
        String tenantIdentifier = TenantContext.getCurrentTenant();
        final Connection connection = getAnyConnection();
        try {
            if (tenantIdentifier != null) {
                connection.createStatement().execute("USE " + tenantIdentifier);
            } else {
                connection.createStatement().execute("USE " + DEFAULT_TENANT_ID);
            }
        }
        catch ( SQLException e ) {
            throw new HibernateException(
                    "Problem setting schema to " + tenantIdentifier,
                    e
            );
        }
        return connection;
    }

    @Override
    public void releaseConnection(String tenantIdentifier, Connection connection) throws SQLException {
        try {
            connection.createStatement().execute( "USE " + DEFAULT_TENANT_ID );
        }
        catch ( SQLException e ) {
            throw new HibernateException(
                   "Problem setting schema to " + tenantIdentifier,
                    e
            );
        }
        connection.close();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    @Override
    public boolean isUnwrappableAs(Class unwrapType) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public <T> T unwrap(Class<T> unwrapType) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean supportsAggressiveRelease() {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but actully i am able to connect to two schemas via two data sources hence  multi-tenancy support is not needed the only thing is while connecting to two separate schemas  i am creating models(enitities) and JPA repositories twices even though tables are identical in both the schemas , is there are a to remove code duplicacy